# sql for data validation between two tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables (Table1 and Table2) I am comparing. Each table has the same four columns: customerid, channeltreeid, producttreeid and consentstatusid. The customerid is what links each record in the tables, but there are cases where customerid is the same but there are different values in the other column. How can I find all such records (those where customerid is the same but at least one other column differs)?

Comment: setup a simple query using a join on the ID, include all columns from table 1 & 2 then do a simple case statement to work out which column values do not match

Comment: Why are you not storing the same customer information in the same table? That way, you to avoid having to worry about this problem.

Comment: I also agree with @Zack you should normalize your data

Comment: You haven't even specified that `customerid` is unique in each table.

Answer (score 1):

I am enhancing the answer given by @TheImpaler to output ONLY the rows where there is a difference in one or more of the 3 last columns, as it is so I understand the requirements.

```
select
    t1.customerid,
    t1.channeltreeid, t1.producttreeid, t1.consentstatusid,
    t2.channeltreeid, t2.producttreeid, t2.consentstatusid,
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.customerid = t2.customerid
where t1.channeltreeid <> t2.channeltreeid
or t1.producttreeid <> t2.producttreeid
or t1.consentstatusid <> t2.consentstatusid
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple join will do:

```
select
    t1.customerid,
    t1.channeltreeid, t1.producttreeid, t1.consentstatusid,
    t2.channeltreeid, t2.producttreeid, t2.consentstatusid,
  from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t1.customerid = t2.customerid
```

In any case, I really think this is a bad database modelling. You should revise and fix the model.